# Any way to calculate chances of getting "n" hits when rolling "x" die (hit is when I roll more than "y")?

Tags: probability, dice

First, let me preface - I saw similar questions already, but to be honest, I didn't understand the answers, or couldn't understand how to convert the answer for given question to my problem.

My problem is:

I have "x", fair, 6-sided die (let's say 3 die)

I count "hit" when at least specific number will be rolled (for example, hit might be from 4, giving 50% chance from single dice, or it can be from 3, giving 66% change).

I need to calculate probability of hitting at least given number of times.

For example: assuming I have 3 die, hit counts from 5 (so 1/3 chance of hitting with each die), I have:

- 70.3% chance of hitting at least once
- 25.9% chance of hitting at least twice
- 3.7% chance of hitting three times

For small number of die, I can simply count by generating all possible sets of results in some program, and then get the hit counts, but with 10 die there are over 60 million possible combinations, and it doesn't look sensible to generate all these sets, just to count how many of them "work".

Is there any simple equation I could use in my program to get the percentages?

Please note that I am not, by far, a mathematician, so my understanding of formulas might be lower than you're generally accustomed to, please dumb-down your answer :)

Comment: Have you learned the binomial distribution, or at least learned permutations and combinations ?

Comment: No. I had something about permutations and combinations, but I was in school over 20 years ago, so my memory of this is not really great.

Comment: nyway - thanks to help from irc, I was able to write a ruby program that does the calculation for me: http://pastie.org/10840841

Comment: All's well that ends well !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several dice, and you want to know what chance you have of getting a specific formula, then the solution is P = (h+m)^n, where h is the chance of hits, m is the chances of missing, and n is the number of dice involved.

This expands out to a polynomial, eg for 3, h³ + 3h²m + 3hm² + m³.

So if your chance of hitting is say 2 (ie 5, 6), and your miss is 4, (ie 1,2,3,4), this comes out to

8 tri-hits,  3*4*4 = 48 bi-hits,  3*2*16 = 96 hits and 4*4*4 = 64 misses.  The sum of these numnbers ought be 216 tosses.

You use the row of the pascal triangle, along with powers of the hit/miss ratio, as

```
  8   7   6   5    4    3    2     1      0   hits out of 8
```

---

```
  1   8  28  56   70   56   28     8      1   ie  n! / h! m!
256 128  64  32   16    8    4     2      1   hits   ie  2^h
  1   4  16  64  256 1024 4096 16384  65536   misses ie  4^m
```

n! means 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * ... n!  It is the factorial.

The first line counts all the different ways of arranging say two hits and six misses (at any probability), ie hmmmhmmm  and hmhmmmm are both counted.

The second line counts the possible ways of getting 6 hits, eg 5,6,5,5,6,5  six hits.  There are 64 ways of doing this.

The third line counts the possible ways of getting misses, so 2,2,4,3,1 is a way of getting 5 misses.

The total of the row is (H+M)^n, the total possible throws over all the dice.  In the present case, H=2, M=4, and H+M=6 possible values, so you have 6^8 = 1679616 possible throws.

The number of 4 hits from 8 die is then 70*16*256/1679616 = 0.170705685

This formula can be implemented in code to handle a large number of throws.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the case where "dumbing down" is definitely necessary. Also, your first "equation" - P=(h+m)^n. Wouldn't h+m be always 1 ?

Comment: Yes, it would always be one, but we want the expansion.  The opening is just pre-amble.  Start at the code but, and work from there.  It's all nicely set for eight-die, with 5 and 6 as hits.

Comment: OK. Then - next thing, the paragraph starting from "8 tri hits". how did you get these values? these are the values that I need to get, and I can't find a way to calculate them. I don't see how you would arrive at the bi/tri hit counts easily... what am i missing?

Comment: 8 trihits is 1 * 2 * 2 * 2.  There is one combination of hhh.  Each hit represents a 5 or 6, giving two ways, so there are 8 different tri-hits.  There is a total of 216 possible throws, gives 8/216 = 0.037037

Comment: yeah, but how did you get the numbers for bi hits or single hits? To be more specific. Given that we have, so far, numbers: 3 (number of die), 2 (number of "scores per dice that count as hit") and 4 (number of "scores per dice that count as miss") - can you tell me how did you arrive at numbers: 8, 48, 96 and 64? 64 seems to be simple, as it can be 6^(number of die)-(8+48+96), but what about 8/48/96? what formula did you use to calculate them?

Comment: When you calculate bi-hits, there are three ways of this happening (hhm, hmh, hhm), and hh is any of (55, 56, 65, 66) and m is any of (1,2,3,4).  So there are in total, 3 * 4 * 4 ways of getting two hits, and 3 * 2 * 16 = 96 ways of getting a single hit.

Comment: sorry, don't get it. well, clearly i'm not smart enough to understand it. I don't understand where you're getting the numbers from. There are 3 ways (which I understand), and then you're multuiplying 3 * 4 * 4, which seems arbitrary to me - I mean - it has to be correct, but I don't see how you arrived at 3 * 4 * 4 from the (hhm, hmh, mhh) list.

Comment: When you count a possibility, there are number of ways of getting six hits if you threw one dice eight times.  This is called a combination, and the formula is given by eg 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8 total ways, divided by the possible ways of hits (1*2*3*4*5*6), and by the way of possible misses (1*2).  This gives 28 ways of getting six hits.  Now the possible hits are (5 or 6) in each of the six places, that is, 2^6 = 64.  The possible misses are given by (1,2,3,4) in each of the two misses, ie 4*4 = 16.  So there are 28*64*16 possible ways of making "six hits".  There are 6^8 ways of getting 8 throws.

Comment: This means that there are 28*64*16 possible ways of getting six hits out of the 6^8 ways (1679616 throws).  So the chance of getting six hits is 0.017 070 568 of all possible throws is six hits.